# Best Practice for Unit Testing Enum Translator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

What is the best practice for unit testing these kind of methods?

```
public VerificationResultCode Translate(int value)
    {
        VerificationResultCode result;

        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(VerificationResultCode), (int)value))
            result = (VerificationResultCode)((int)value);
        else
            throw new UnknownResultReturnFromGatewayException();

        return result;
    }
```

VerificationResultCode is Enum Type like:

```
public enum VerificationResultCode 
{
        BankingNetworkError = 100,
        NotEqual =101,
        InputFormatError = 102,
        MerchantAuthenticationFailed = 103,

...
}
```

Should we write a single test method for each of Enum Members or just write **one** test method with lots of Assertions?

Comment: For one, you should not encode integers as doubles. You will have spurious failures.

Comment: Two tests. One with a correct value, one with an incorrect value. Watch that you don't get an exception, then that you do get an exception. Anything else you're unit testing the CLR's ability to cast from an integer to an enumeration.

Comment: What are you testing? the enum or the Translate method? If it's the latter then one valid value and one invalid (with expected exception) should do it. If the former then you are going to need some externalised resource with the definitions in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is almost too trivial to unit test.  You should unit test the behavior that depends on the `VerificationResultCode` which will also test the `Translate` function.  A bigger question is why do you need a public translation function instead of encapsulating it in objects?

Comment: its a small snippet from Brownfield application that we trying to refactor, enhance and adding some unit test.

Comment: If you are refactoring legacy code, then you need to pick your test seams at a large enough granularity that you can refactor within your tests.  Unit testing small translation functions like your example may be counterproductive because when you refactor you will break dozens of these micro unit tests.

Comment: thanks for your answer. you said this code is too trivial for unit testing. But this section is small snippet of some payment gateway with lots of web service call and data access logic.I think if i test the behavior that depends on enumeration Its kinda like Integration Test.

Comment: You will need refactor the data access/web service so you can inject those dependencies with fakes before you run a unit test.  Write tests when you need to refactor, add features, or further understand legacy code.  Don't add tests just for the sake of having unit tests.  [This book may help](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?WorkingEffectivelyWithLegacyCode).